# replace the value of a nested object if key exists

Tags: javascript

I have an array with nested objects. What I want to achieve is to loop through the arrays objects and check if a key exists inside the object and if it does I want to replace the value of that object and break out of the loop. If the key doesn't exist inside any of the objects I want to append a new object into the array and print the final array. What I tried below is not working. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```js
x = [{
  "s": "23",
  "t": "41"
}, {
  "e": "29",
  "t": "87"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if ("d" in x[i]) {
    x[i]["t"] = "21"
    console.log(x)
    break
  } else if (i === x.length - 1) {
    x.push({
      "d": "22",
      "t": "77"
    })
    console.log(x)

    //loop finised
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get? It would help make the question clearer.

Comment: A second `break` just before `//loop finised` will also fix it, but I think @Abdulrahman Ali 's answer is better

Comment: The mistake here was that x.length is apparently not set at the beginning of the loop, but is checked each time whether the length is reached. But since a new element is always appended before, the length is never reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working because it enters an infinite loop. You're mutating the array directly(by adding/pushing a new element) while looping through it. So the length keeps getting longer & longer resulting in infinite loop.

Just change your code to the following:

```js
x = [{
  "s": "23",
  "t": "41"
}, {
  "e": "29",
  "t": "87"
}]

let isKeyExists = false;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if ("d" in x[i]) {
    x[i]["t"] = "21"
    console.log(x)
    isKeyExists = true;
    break
  }  
}

if (!isKeyExists) {
  x.push({
      "v": "22",
      "t": "77"
  })
}

console.log(x)
```

In the code above, you just add the object after you have exited the loop.

Comment: this will push the new object even if the key is found inside the array. I want to push the new object only if the key inside the if statement is not found.

Comment: @seriously, got it. Just added the code. You only need a boolean flag to specify whether the key was ever found.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not working because you are trying to access the d key in the x array, but the d key does not exist in any of the objects in the x array. You can fix this by checking if the d key exists in the current object before you try to access it. You can do this by using the hasOwnProperty() method.

Here is the corrected code:

```
x = [{
  "s": "23",
  "t": "41"
}, {
  "e": "29",
  "t": "87"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].hasOwnProperty("d")) {
    x[i]["t"] = "21"
    console.log(x)
    break
  } else if (i === x.length - 1) {
    x.push({
      "v": "22",
      "t": "77"
    })
    console.log(x)

    //loop finised
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for the same reason as in the question.